# Object dropdown missing "Server Objects & Events"

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In VS2008 source view, the left side object dropdown is missing "Server Objects & Events", and "Server Code".  I would like to know how to enable these to be visible.

The controls on the page do contain runat="server".

Comment: Sorry didn't get the issue. And we are talking about asp.net controls and not html correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those items only appear if you are using a single-page model for your code (i.e., html and code are both in the aspx page with no code-behind). If you are using a code-behind file, then you will not get those options while looking at the page's source view.

See the yellow box part way down [this page in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1kx90fb%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new asp page clear the check box for place code in separate file.This ensures that the IDE puts all code within .aspx file .
after do that...

go to :

Tools > options > Text editor >All languages >General >>>> tick the navigation bar check box
.